# NotImplementedError: pwmio not supported for this board

Tags: nvidia-jetson-nano

I am trying to control a servo using JetsonNano and a PCA9685 board. I am on Jetpack 4.3 and using python3. After a recent update I started to end up with the following error.

"NotImplementedError: pwmio not supported for this board"

`from adafruit_servokit import ServoKit`

`kit=ServoKit(channels=16)`

`kit.servo[0].angle=90                 ## Horizontal motion`

`kit.servo[1].angle=0                ## Vertical Motion`

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same issue at JetPack 4.6.
On JetPack 4.5.1 everything ok. I think something wrong with L4T 32.6.1...